# ¿Cómo manejar Optional con findById de JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Quiero usar `findById`

```
User user=userDto.findById(idUser);
```

y obtengo este error al compilar mi proyecto:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Optional to Use

Como hago para obtener un objeto de tipo `User` en vez de un `Optional`?

Estoy usando eclipse, parece que es un error del IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por definicion, el `findById(...)` te devuelve un objeto de tipo `Optional` como pudiste darte cuenta. Dentro de el `Optional` viene encapsulada una posible respuesta.

Esto sucede con la intencion de "forzar" al programador a considerar la posibilidad de que no se encuentre un recurso con ese id.

Entonces, lo deberias poder manejar de la siguiente manera:

```
Optional<User> optionalUser = userDto.findById(idUser);

if (!optionalUser.isPresent()) {
   // Manejar el error
   throw new Exception("No se encontro el usuario.");
}

User user = optionalUser.get();
```

Te recomiendo leer un poco acerca de [Optional](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2015/03/02/optional-java-8/). Es util ;)